# I (haven't / hadn't) really thought about that

Tags: tense

> A : Do you like me?
>
> B : Yes
>
> A : As friends?
>
> B : Yeah. I mean, I don't know. I ***(haven't / hadn't)*** really thought about that.

.

> I ***haven't*** really thought about that.

I didn't think about that before and I don't know now as well. (chances are I don't like you)

.

> I ***hadn't*** really thought about that.

I didn't think about that before, but it's only past that I didn't think. There's a big time difference between past and present by using "hadn't". And, now that I think of it, it could be different from before.(chances are I like you)

.

Am I right to think this way? I know it's not perfectly right but I just have a feeling like that.

Which one would you say when you like her.

Comment: I don't agree with either of the answers below. I interpret _hadn't_ as _I hadn't thought about it until you asked me_, suggesting that perhaps I am thinking about it now as I speak. _Haven't_ doesn't have that implication - doesn't rule it out, but doesn't suggest it, and so is more non-committal.

Comment: What about "I wasn't thinking of it"?

Answer (score 0):

The difference between "**haven't thought**" and "**hadn't thought**" is that the former speaks about an event that started in the past (probably recently) and is still on-going whereas the latter speaks about an event that ended in the past before a certain other event that happened afterward.

Answer (score 0):

Use of Past perfect tense (hadn't) would imply that her process of thinking started somewhere in past and ended at some other point, that too in the past.

"I haven't thought about it." may imply that the Thinking(verb) process is still impending.